# Logstash - splitting the log into a csv file

Tags: csv, elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok

I want to use logstash to separate the appropriate logs by a constant value appearing in these logs, and then divide the log into pieces after the separator ("|") and put it into a csv file with headers. The logs I'm looking for are recognized by the constant (WID2). I also noticed that the message pulled out by GREEDYDATA gets cut off after about 85 characters

Example log:
2022-01-02 10:32:30,0000001 | WID2 | 3313141414 | Request | STEP_1 | OK | Message

And i want from this logs create csv file with headers: TIMESTAMP, VALUE, MESSAGE_TYPE, STEP, STATUS, MESSAGE. I do not want to save a constant value (WID2) in the csv file, it only serves to find my logs among others.

I wrote it but it doesn't work:

```
input {
 file {
  path => ["path"]
  start_position => "beginning"
  sincedb_path => "path"
 }
}

filter {
 grok {
  match => {
   "message" => "%{GREEDYDATA:SYSLOGMESSAGE}"
    }
   }
 if ([SYSLOGMESSAGE] !~ "WID2"){
  drop {}
 }
 if([SYSLOGMESSAGE] =~ 'WID2") {
  csv {
   separator => "|"
   columns => ["TIMESTAMP", "VALUE", "MESSAGE_TYPE", "STEP", "STATUS", "MESSAGE"]
  }
 }
}

output{
 file {
  path => ["path.csv"]
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your log messages have this format:

```
2022-01-02 10:32:30,0000001 | WID2 | 3313141414 | Request | STEP_1 | OK | Message
```

And you want to parse every message that has `WID2` on it, the following filter will work.

```
filter {
    if "WID2" in [message] {
        csv {
            separator => "|"
            columns => ["TIMESTAMP", "[@metadata][wid2]", "VALUE", "MESSAGE_TYPE", "STEP", "STATUS", "MESSAGE"]
        }
    } else {
        drop {}
    }
}
```

The `if` conditional will test if `WID2` is present in the message, if it is true, it will use the `csv` filter to parse it, since the second column of your csv is the value `WID2` and you do not want to save it, you can store its value in the field `[@metadata][wid2]`, this metadata field will not be present in the output block.

If the string `WID2` is not present in the message field, the event is dropped.